# Converting Python Multiprocessing to PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, multiprocessing

Hello I'm trying to convert my use of multiprocessing in Python to PySpark. I'm no expert in PySpark so I'm trying to understand first if it's possible to do so. And if it is, how can I do it?

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import pandas as pd

def connectToDB():
    # BLABLABLA
    return connectionInstance, cursorInstance 

def construct_each_company(tmpDF_forPeerGroup, ii, start_str, end_str):

    connectionInstance, cursorInstance = connectToDB()
    sql = "SELECT * FROM DataBase.Scores WHERE company_idx = "+str(idx)+" AND timestamp BETWEEN '"+start_str+"' AND '"+end_str+"'"
    tmpDF = pd.read_sql(sql, con=connectionInstance)

    return (ii, tmpList_forThisCompany, parall_Name)

def main():
    tmpDF_forPeerGroup = ['company1','company2','company3','company4','company5']
    start_str = "2019-06-20"
    end_str = "2019-10-17"

    pool = mp.Pool(8)

    results = pool.starmap_async(construct_each_company, [(tmpDF_forPeerGroup, i, start_str, end_str) for i in range(0, len(tmpDF_forPeerGroup))]).get()
    pool.close()

    results.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
    finalListForCompanies = [r2 for (r1, r2, r3) in results]
```

I'm currently facing issues with Python multiprocessing as it gets stuck when I try aggregating over 150 tables eventually (I don't know why). My MySQL database request limit is of 600 so I don't understand why it gets stuck.

Comment: any ideas or recommendations?

Comment: You can simply call `spark.sql('SELECT * FROM DataBase.Scores WHERE company_idx IN (....) AND timestamp BETWEEN '"+start_str+"' AND '"+end_str+"'"')`. Spark will try to parallize it for you.

Comment: @cronoik I'd like to parallelise the iterations through the companies. How does it work? Do I do a for loop?

Comment: Spark works a bit differently because Spark tries to parallize it for you. You can modify the level of paralleziation, but you can't set it directly like you do in python or other programming languages (i.e. pyspark is not just python on a cluster!). In case you want to do that, you should start several spark jobs.